# FluentValidation as a Composite Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, clean-architecture

I have a table that has a composite key on it.

```
GroupCode     GroupRec     oDescription
T             123          ......
T             321          ......
K             123          ......
M             123          ......
```

The key is with `GroupCode` and `GroupRec`.

I want to apply the composite key to the FluentValidation rule. How can I do that?

I have the following code as a validator:

```
private readonly IApplicationDBContext _context;

public CreateGroupingCommandValidator(IApplicationDBContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    RuleFor(v => v.GroupCode)
        .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.")
        .MustAsync(BeUniqueName).WithMessage("Already exists.")
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required.");

    RuleFor(v => v.GroupRec)
        .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.")
        .MustAsync(BeUniqueName).WithMessage("Already exists.")
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required.");

    RuleFor(v => v.oDescription)
        .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.");
}

private async Task<bool> BeUniqueName(string codename, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await _context.Mrekcs.AllAsync(x => x.GroupCode != codename, cancellationToken);
}
```

How can I modify the `BeUniqueName` into a composite key?
Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have implemented a function to validate the unique composite key as below:

```cs
private async Task<bool> BeUniqueCompositeKey(string groupCode, string groupRec, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await _context.Mrekcs.AllAsync(x => x.GroupCode != groupCode && x.GroupRec != groupRec, cancellationToken);
}
```

In the FluentValidation rule for `GroupCode`, you can implement by passing a delegate async function to `MustAsync` as below:

```cs
RuleFor(v => v.GroupCode)
        .MaximumLength(50)
        .WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.")
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Required.")
        .MustAsync(async (root, groupCode, context) => 
        {
            return await BeUniqueCompositeKey(groupCode, root.GroupRec, new CancellationToken());
        })
        .WithMessage("Duplicate Composite key: GroupCode & GroupRec");
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k5kIfA)

Answer (score 0):

You can split out your rules and let `BeUniqueName` take in your model as opposed to a `string`

```cs
private readonly IApplicationDBContext _context;

    public CreateGroupingCommandValidator(IApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        RuleFor(v => v.GroupCode)
            .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required.");

        RuleFor(v => v.GroupRec)
            .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required.");

        RuleFor(v => v)
            .MustAsync(BeUniqueName).WithMessage("Already exists.")

        RuleFor(v => v.oDescription)
            .MaximumLength(50).WithMessage("Maximum length is 50.");
    }

    private async Task<bool> BeUniqueName(CreateGrouping grouping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _context.Mrekcs.AllAsync(x => x.GroupCode != grouping.GroupCode && x.GroupRec != grouping.GroupRec, cancellationToken);
    }
```